# Check date between two dates in T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, between

I have a stored procedure where want check that a date is between a fixed date and the current date/time (with `GETDATE()`):

```
SELECT
    a, b
FROM myTbl
WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN 'Day start datetime' AND GETDATE()
```

...for example :

```
WHERE
    DATE BETWEEN '2013-09-10 00:00:00.00' AND 'GETDATE()'
```

How to do it?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A pair of `DATEADD`/`DATEDIFF` calls will round a date down to the previous midnight:

```
SELECT a , b
FROM myTbl
WHERE DATE BETWEEN DATEADD(day,DATEDIFF(day,0,GETDATE()),0) and GETDATE()
```

Alternatively, if you're on SQL Server 2008 or later:

```
SELECT a , b
FROM myTbl
WHERE DATE BETWEEN CONVERT(date,GETDATE()) and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 8):

`'GETDATE()'` is a string literal, `GETDATE()` is a `T-SQL` function.

Your query should look like:

```
SELECT a , b
FROM myTbl
WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013-09-10 00:00:00.0' and GETDATE()
```

Answer (score 1):

I think `WHERE DATE BETWEEN '2013-09-10 00:00:00.00' and GETDATE()` (without the single quotes around the `GETDATE()` call) should work just fine.

Comment: '2013-09-10 00:00:00.00' this is for example , tomorrow it will be dont correctly work , I nedd current date start time

Comment: Ok, I didn't get that from the question. The correct answer is given by @Damien_The_Unbeliever then.

Answer (score 0):

You can get `Day start date time` by converting Getdate() return value to a Date type and again to Datetime as below.

```
select a,b
from myTbl
where [date] between convert(datetime,convert([date], getdate())) 
                 and getdate()
```